# How right is to set grub booter file to control fan acpi by linux

Tags: grub2, kernel, bootloader, fan, acpi

What is the right stroke to set in grub booter file to control fan by linux
for notebook Acer TravelMate 4652LMi

1. osi_acpi=Linux or
2. acpi_osi=Linux
3. or some other parameter

Comment: Why are you asking 3 options ?